# Django can not connect to MySQL container?

Tags: mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose like a bellow:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    env_file: ./src/.environment
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
  web:
    build:
      context: ./src
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && python manage.py makemigrations --no-input && python manage.py migrate --no-input"
    env_file: ./src/.environment
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/project/src
      - staticfiles:/var/www/project/src/statics
```

.environment content as follow:

```
DATABASE_MYSQL_NAME=dataCollection
DATABASE_MYSQL_HOST=mysql
DATABASE_MYSQL_USER=user1
DATABASE_MYSQL_PASSWORD=user123456
DATABASE_MYSQL_PORT=3306
```

Then in django setting I have follow database configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': os.getenv('DATABASE_MYSQL_NAME'),
            'HOST': os.getenv('DATABASE_MYSQL_HOST'),
            'USER': os.getenv('DATABASE_MYSQL_USER'),
            'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DATABASE_MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
            'PORT': os.getenv('DATABASE_MYSQL_PORT'),
        }
    }
```

But, when I run `docker-comose up` it throws the following error:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' (115)")
```

I don't know what the problem is?

Comment: If you run `docker-compose up -d`, wait 30-60 seconds, and run the same command again, does it work the second time?  Are there other interesting things in the Compose logs?

Comment: @DavidMaze When I run `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up` it throws this error the first time. But, after that, I press `Ctrl+c`, and then `docker-compose up` it works. it is strange!!

Comment: @DavidMaze don't have any idea?